# How to include django template file from an install python package?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an install python package with structure

```
myapp 
   templates/
          myapp/
               base.html
```

and my project with structure

```
myproject
      testapp/
           templates/
               layout.html
```

I install the package myapp into myproject and from the `layout.html` file I want to extend the file `base.html` from the package myapp.

Normally, if myapp is a local app inside myproject I can simply do

```
{% extends myapp/base.html %}
```

But if myapp is a install package how can I do that ?